# Does this.$route automatically added to parameter when using this.$router.push()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Like the title said, when I'm using this.$router.push(), does this.$route automatically added to the parameter?

I already asked a friend, and he said so. I'm myself not really sure if that is true. I already read the documentation, and found nothing about it.

So basically, the code is :

```
//inside some function
myObject = {
   a:1
   b:2
   ...
   //doesn't really matter
}

this.$router.push({query: myObject})
```

I don't send `name` or `path` as a parameter, the router.push still work as expected. So how `this.$router.push` still work even though I didn't send `name` or `path` to match it to `VueRouter({array_of_routes})`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it seems when no `name` or `path` were given, then this.$router gonna push to current path. (reloading the page)